# How to extract div content using grep?

Tags: grep

I need to extract specific div content within the file.

The content is as follows.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">One of three columns</div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <p>One of three columns</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">One of three columns</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following content needs to be extracted.

```
<div class="col-6">
    <p>One of three columns</p>
</div>
```

I try to do this.

```
cat test.html | tr -d '\n\t' | grep -o "<div class=\"col-6\">.*<\/div><div class=\"col-4\">"
```

Return as follows.

```
<div class="col-6"><p>One of three columns</p></div><div class="col-4">
```

How do I remove the before and after parts of the content?

```
<div class="col-6">...</div><div class="col-4">
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Don't try to parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1041364), have you tried using an XML parser instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grep -A`

```
$ grep -A 2 'class="col-6"' test.html | sed -n 2p
        <p>One of three columns</p>
```

From `man grep`:

> `-A NUM`, `--after-context=NUM`
> Print  `NUM`  lines  of  trailing  context  after  matching lines.

or use `awk`:

```
$ awk '/class="col-6"/{getline; print $0}' test.html
        <p>One of three columns</p>
```

---

Note: This works only if the structure stays exactly like your test input.
In general I would **always** prefer a proper xml / html parser.

e.g. `python`'s `beautifulsoup`:

```
$ python3 -c '
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("test.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp)
print(soup.findAll("div", {"class":"col-6"})[0].findAll("p")[0])'
<p>One of three columns</p>
```

Or using `xmlstarlet` like this:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//div[@class="col-6"]' -c './p' -n test.html
<p>One of three columns</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! How to remove `<div class="col-6">.... </div><div class="col-4">`, I just need to get the `p` element.